# Silverlight 4 closeable tabs in TabControl

Tags: silverlight, tabcontrol

I have close button in the header of each tab of TabControl. Tabs are created dynamically in code and a datatemplate (in which the close button was defined) is applied. Now I want close-buttons to be visible only when tab is active. Is it possible to bind button's visibility property to tabitem's activeness (probably IsSelected property)? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look [Kent's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423533/on-the-wpf-tabcontrol-can-i-add-content-next-to-the-tab-headers). There's also some [sample code](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-infrastructure-activeawarecommand.html) on his blog.

Comment: I choose your answer correct without seeing details because I already took that root and achieved what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to achieve if you put close button in TabHeader template instead of datatemplate.

Comment: Actually a datatemplate is applied as HeaderTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be a solution:

http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/09/08/relativesource-binding-with-findancestor-mode-in-silverlight/